Jmeter: how to post one html request for each request from the previous group
I am working on scheduling stress tests on Jmeter: I have html requests that post the messages payload, and then in a tearDown thread a different html request (because I need it to run only when the first part has finished) that sends a query with the messageId exctracted from the previous thread, to be sure that every message has been actually sent.
So I have a POST request that with this path /api/console/proxy?path=_search&method=GET asks for this query:
{"query": {"bool": {"must":[ {"match_phrase":{"messageSid":{"query":"${__property(mexid)}"}}}]} } }

What I need to do is to send exactly as many queries as the number of mexid extracted from the previous thread.
So if for example I end up sending 173 messages, I need exactly 173 queries, one for each mexid.

One of possible options would be writing all the occurrences of the mexid to a CSV file using i.e. Flexible File Writer
Then in the tearDown Thread Group you will be able to use CSV Data Set Config to read the values from the CSV file, if you configure it to stop on EOF it will run as many times as there are lines in the CSV file.

I see, but I guess the csv would be written at the end of the run, so I wouldn't be able to use it in the same run for the second part :(
Is there maybe a way to count the number of requests at the end of part 1, and save it as a variable to use in the "number of users" field in part 2? Am I talking nonsense? (I'm still fairly new to this)

OR MAYBE! Is there a way to translate the whole Part2 html request to code and add it directly to Part1 (like a JSR223 sampler maybe?) with a nice: foreach (mexid as mexidb) {post this html request} or something like that?
